# How much time does Apple take to publish and unpublish and app?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

I am new to this field. I have made an app, but making it public I need the app store link that when clicked will redirect it to app store. I need this link to embed it into other app which should be published with the desired app simultaneously.

So the problem is I need App1 link to embed it into App2. 
Both App1 and App2 should be published simultaneously.

My Solution: I want to push App 1 to apple store and publish it. I'll get the link, as soon as I get it, I'll unpublished it. But the issue is some user can get notified, which is I think depends on the time for which app will be online.

My question: so I want to know two things:
1) how much average time does it take from publishing the app and get it reflected in app store (let's call it 'birth time' :p)
2) after unpublishing it (remove from sale in Apple's language) how time will it take to get out from the app store (let's call it 'sleep time')

my plan is, after getting the link, I'll embed it into App2, and on a fine morning I'll again republish App1 along with App 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you create the record for your app in App Store Connect you can get the `Apple ID number` - you can use this to create the App Store URL. You don't need to actually publish the app.

It is recommended that you use [`SKStoreProductViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller) to provide the ability to install one app from inside the other. Again, all you need for that is the Apple ID from App Store Connect.